# What if we skip polarization in geometric quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, phase-space, quantization

In QM, we most frequently work with "position-space" representation of the CCR
$$
\mathcal{H} = L_2(\mathbb{R}, dx), \quad
X = x, \quad
P = - i \hbar \frac{d}{dx}.
$$

Sometimes it's useful to work with the "momentum-space" representation
$$
\mathcal{H} = L_2(\mathbb{R}, dp), \quad
X = i \hbar \frac{d}{dp}, \quad
P = p.
$$

It's a well-known fact that these two representations are unitarily equivalent, the unitary map between the two being the Fourier transform.

In fact, a more general statement is the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem): any two representations of the CCR are unitarily equivalent (well, actually, of the Weyl algebra, but it's essentially the same thing for the purposes of this question).

I am interested in the following "symmetric" representation of the CCR:
$$
\mathcal{H} = L_2(\mathbb{R}^2, dx dp), \quad
X = x + \frac{i \hbar}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial p}, \quad
P = p - \frac{i \hbar}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}.
$$

It's straightforward to see that $[X, P] = i \hbar$ is satisfied.

**My questions are:**

1. How can I build an isomorphism between this "symmetric" representation and the "position-space" representation the existence of which is guaranteed by the Stone-von Neumann theorem?
2. Does this isomorphism have any physical significance that's noteworthy?

---

What follows is some (optional) background on why this representation is interesting to me.

This formula is inspired by [Geometric Quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization), where we build the "pre-quantum Hilbert space" before we choose the [polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization#Polarization) to cut down the "excessive size". In this example, polarisation would account for only letting the wavefunction depend on say $x$, and adjusting the operators accordingly.

Since geometric quantization is most usually applied to compact manifolds (sphere, torus, etc.) where the quantum theory acts on a finite dimensional vector space, polarization is an important step to have the "correct" quantum theory.

However, for the case of a plane $(x,p)$, both the pre-quantum and the polarised spaces are isomorphic, because they both are just the abstract Hilbert space. Furthermore, both the prequantum operators and polarised operators give representations of the CCR which must be equivalent due to the Stone-von Neumann theorem.

This seems to suggest that polarisation is somehow not necessary when working with non-compact phase spaces?

Comment: No offense, but from a physics perspective none of this is "correct" quantum theory. The only "correct" theory we have, at this moment, is relativistic quantum field theory and the physical ontology of QFT is certainly not satisfied by a mixed representation. From an experimental physics perspective none of the von Neumann formalism is physical. We always have a phenomenological interpretation layer between the theory and actual observations. QM textbooks rarely mention this and atomic etc. physics textbooks seem to assume that the student can already make the translation.

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't understand your comment at all. QM is an approximation but does it make it any less correct? Does it make it wrong to wonder about the mathematical foundations of QM even though it's not the most fundamental theory out there? In any case, if you read my question carefully, you'll notice that I mention the equivalence of all three representations for ordinary QM, a result known as the SvN theorem. So the mixed representation is really no different from position-space or momentum-space.

Comment: Nonrelativistic QM is not a self-consistent theory and while von Neumann's Hilbert space formalism gives us a useful mathematical framework, it also hides the actual physical processes. To a theorist this may be irrelevant, but to both the phenomenologist and the experimentalist it provides an additional hurdle. I did not say that these transformations are "wrong" but math that "is not wrong" still does not automatically satisfy a "physicality" condition. non-relativistic QM is not a physical theory, so if you are looking for the "correct" one, then you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @FlatterMann non-relativistic QM **is** self-consistent, if you disagree with this I’m happy to discuss this in the chat on this website.

Comment: Happy to discuss.

Comment: @FlatterMann I created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139887/is-qm-really-inconsistent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have two representations $(V_1,\pi_1)$ and $(V_2,\pi_2)$ of a group or algebra and an isomorphism $\phi : V_1 \to V_2$, then for any $g$ in the group or algebra that isomorphism must send eigenvectors of $\pi_1(g)$ to eigenvectors of $\pi_2(g)$ with the same eigenvalues by definition of an isomorphism of representations (this is the "intertwiner" part).

So when the eigenstates of $\pi_i(g)$ are non-degenerate and a basis of $V_i$, this already uniquely fixes the isomorphism because for each eigenvector there is only a single possible target. There is a slight subtlety here because $x$ and $p$ only have generalized eigenstates, but the same idea still works: Any $v_1\in V_1$ has a representation as
$$ v_1 = \int f(x)\lvert x\rangle_1\mathrm{d}x$$
where the $\lvert x\rangle_1$ are eigenstates of $\pi_1(x)$ and this gets sent to
$$ \phi(v_1) = \int f(x)\lvert x\rangle_2\mathrm{d}x,$$
i.e. you're just matching wavefunctions. Another way to say this is that you can always construct an isomorphism to the default representation on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ where $x$ is multiplication by mapping any state $\lvert \psi\rangle$ to its position wavefunction $\psi(x) = \langle x\vert \psi\rangle$, and then concatenating these isomorphisms gives you isomorphisms between any two representations of the CCR.

---

Note that the above requires that you already *know* the isomorphism $\phi$ should exist. Your symmetric representation is a representation of the CCR, but in order for us to know that it should be isomorphic to the standard representation on $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathrm{d}x)$ via Stone-von Neumann you also need to know that it is *irreducible*. But this is not the case here: You have *four* operators $x,\partial_x,p,\partial_p$, and so besides your $X = x+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{i}\partial_p$ and $P = p - \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{i}\partial_x$, there are also the linearly-independent operators $X' = x-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{i}\partial_p$ and $P' = p + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{i}\partial_x$ which also fulfill $[X',P'] = [x-\mathrm{i}\partial_p, p + \mathrm{i}\partial_x] = \mathrm{i}$.

So what you have here is a representation of a *two*-dimensional CCR algebra, and in particular the generalized eigenstates of $X$ or $X'$ alone are *not* non-degenerate. For $X,X'$ together, you get non-degenerate eigenstates $\lvert x,x'\rangle$, and then the argument from above gives you maps to wavefunctions $\psi(x,x')$ that allow you to map this to the standard position representation $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2)$ of the CCR in two spatial dimensions.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing this out to me. I've spent some time thinking about this approach, I think there still are difficulties that I'm not sure how to resolve here. When solving for generalized eigenvalue in the position-space representation, we have $x f(x) = a f(x)$ which solves as $f(x) = \delta(x - a)$. However, the symmetric representation equation gives $x f(x,p) - i \hbar \partial f / \partial p = a f(x,p)$ which solves to $f(x,p) = f_0(x) e^{- i \hbar^{-1} p (x - a)}$ with $f_0(x)$ seemingly an arbitrary function, not a unique eigenfunction as I would naively expect.

Comment: I suspect this peculiarity is related to the fact that $X$ doesn't have real eigenfunctions, only approximate eigenfunctions; but I'm not clear on how to reconcile this consistently. E.g. I want to map some notoriously famous wavefunctions, like the ground state of the quantum oscillator etc. to the symmetric representation, but to do that I would have to choose a kernel of the mapping $\delta(x - a) \mapsto f_0(x) e^{-i \hbar^{-1} p (x-a)}$ which depends on the choice of $f_0$. I can't figure out how this arbitrariness can be resolved if there's any way at all. Do you have any insights?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Your representation is "too large" - it is not actually an irreducible representation of the 1d CCR. I've added an explanation of that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Concerning OP's 3 representations$^1$ of the [Heisenberg algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heisenberg+Lie+algebra), we can put them on equal footing as follows:
   $${\cal A}(x,\partial_x)~\cong~ \{ A\in {\cal A}(x,p,\partial_x,\partial_p)\mid [A,p]~=~0 ~\wedge~ [\partial_p,A]~=~0\}, $$
   $$ {\cal A}(p,\partial_p)~\cong~ \{ A\in {\cal A}(x,p,\partial_x,\partial_p)\mid [A,x]~=~0 ~\wedge~ [\partial_x,A]~=~0\}, $$
   $$\begin{align} & {\cal A}(x+ \frac{i \hbar}{2}\partial_p,p- \frac{i \hbar}{2}\partial_x)\cr
   ~\cong~& \{ A\in {\cal A}(x,p,\partial_x,\partial_p)\mid [A,x- \frac{i \hbar}{2}\partial_p]~=~0 ~\wedge~ [A,p+ \frac{i \hbar}{2}\partial_x]~=~0\}. \end{align}$$
   These algebras are isomorphic, which can be seen via appropriate change of coordinates.
2. Similarly, we can consider [Poisson algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_algebra) ${\cal A}(x^1,x^2,p_1,p_2)$ with 2 [second-class constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint). The $L^2$ Hilbert spaces of sough-for Schrödinger representations/[polarizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization#Polarization) is in this setting then a matter of choosing$^2$ a [Lagrangian subspace](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lagrangian+subspace), possibly via appropriate change of coordinates.

--

$^1$ Here ${\cal A}(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ denotes the algebra generated by the elements $t_1,\ldots,t_n$.

$^2$ We should here choose 1 coordinate out of 4.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your answer I think, it proves the equivalence of algebras freely generated by those pairs. I think I’m asking a different question though (unless it’s related in a way I’m not seeing): my question is about how a unitary map (or isomorphism) between the representations of this algebra on $L_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L_2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (defined by position space and symmetric formulas from my question) can be explicitly constructed.

Comment: I updated the answer.